# Extension C# en VS Code no esta funcionando

Tags: c#, vscode

Hola gente como dice el titulo tengo este problema con VS Code y me resulta muy tedioso escribir todo el codigo sin esta extension tan util.

Ya probe desinstalar la extension y volverla a instalar. Mi VS Code esta actualizado asique no se me ocurre cual puede ser el problema

La extension c#

Comment: a cual extension haces referencia ? porque dices que tienes problemas con la extension pero nunca mencionas de cual se trata

Comment: cual es el problema que notas? solo no funciona o tienes algun mensaje de error

Comment: La extension c# como dice el titulo. No me funciona al crear un archivo.cs ya que no me crea el codigo automaticamente. El intellisense parece que anda bien.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te tomes tu tiempo y elabores mejor tu pregunta porque no se entiende lo que intentas transmitir. ¿No te va el autocompletado? ¿No te van los atajos ?¿Esperas que te genere algun codigo inicial y no lo hace?.Por favor detalla mejor tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Habilitaste la extensión en el área de trabajo ? , validaste que no estuviera des habilitado ?

Answer (score 0):

Vuelve a instalar el SDK de .net Core o el que estés usando.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Puedes usar este link para instalarlo.